# Python Selenium: Unable to Find Element After First Refresh

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've seen a few instances of this question, but I was not sure how to apply the changes to my particular situation. I have code that monitors a webpage for changes and refreshes every 30 seconds, as follows:

```
import sys
import ctypes
from time import sleep
from Checker import Checker

USERNAME = sys.argv[1]
PASSWORD = sys.argv[2]


def main():
    crawler = Checker()
    crawler.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    crawler.click_data()
    crawler.view_page()
    while crawler.check_page():
    crawler.wait_for_table()
    crawler.refresh()
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "A change has been made!", "Attention", 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that Selenium will always show an error stating it is unable to locate the element after the first refresh has been made. The element in question, I suspect, is a table from which I retrieve data using the following function:

```
def get_data_cells(self):
    contents = []
    table_id = "table.datadisplaytable:nth-child(4)"
    table = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, table_id)
    cells = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for cell in cells:
        contents.append(cell.text)
    return contents
```

I can't tell if the issue is in the above function or in the `main()`. What's an easy way to get Selenium to refresh the page without returning such an error?

**Update:**

I've added a wait function and adjusted the `main()` function accordinly:

```
def wait_for_table(self):
    table_selector = "table.datadisplaytable:nth-child(4)"
    delay = 60
    try:
        wait = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, table_selector)))
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Operation timeout! The requested element never loaded.")
```

Since the same error is still occurring, either my timing function is not working properly or it is not a timing issue.

Comment: Did you tried to add some time for table complete rendering?

Comment: @Andersson Yes. Please see the update above.

Comment: Please check also whether your table located inside `<frame>` or `<iframe>` block

Comment: @Andersson The table is indeed inside an `<iframe>` block. How does this relate to the error message?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say a `<frame>`, NOT `<iframe>`.

Comment: @Andersson Your hint gave me an idea. I switched frames and it now seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue while doing web scraping before and found that re-sending the GET request (instead of refreshing) seemed to eliminate it.

It's not very elegant, but it worked for me.

Comment: That was actually one of the first workarounds I tried. Zero difference.

Comment: Hmmm, weird. This usually worked for me. You could cry closing the webdriver and then re-starting it (i.e. doing crawler.close() then crawler.get('http://...'). Though that may not be not be fast enough since you said you were doing it every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have fixed my own problem.

My `refresh()` function was written as follows:

```
def refresh():
    self.driver.refresh()
```

All I did was switch frames right after the `refresh()` call. That is:

```
def refresh():
    self.driver.refresh()
    self.driver.switch_to.frame("content")
```

This took care of it. I can see that the page is now refreshing without issues.